# Converting a detail page button to Lightning

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning, custom-button

I am trying to convert a detail page button which sets the default value through the Link URL to the lightning. 
[image]

In the lightning it doesnt work setting the default values (in my other post it was said that this feature will be available in Lightning in the Spring'20 release and suggested the work around can be Quick Actions. I tried the quick Actions but the issue is I cannot set the default values for the lookup fields

[image]

Is there any other way I can approach this using VisualForce Page/ Lightning Component. I am new to Salesforce and  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Lookup field is a reference field. You can set default value by using AccountId instead of Account.Name. Just change your formula from `Opportunity.Account.Name` to `Opportunity.AccountId`